# Odd level translator output waveform from 3MHz

Tags: level-translation

I am using [SN74LVC1T45](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1T45) for level translation from 1.8V to 5V. I have designed a custom board for this. The problem I am facing here is that I am getting desired out from 10Hz to 2MHz but from 3MHz the shape of the output waveform is somewhat odd or in irregular shape when compared to an actual square wave.

I am attaching the schematic I have followed and the snapshot of the output waveform at 1MHz and 4MHz. The output waveform gets worse as I increase the frequency.

I am feeding 1.8Vpp from signal generator and measuring output using high impedance probes.

Please help with this.

Thanks In Advance

Schematic:-
[image: schematic]

1MHz input
[image: 1MHz input waveform]

1MHz output
[image: 1MHz output waveform]

4MHz input
[image: 4MHz input waveform]

4MHz output
[image: 4MHz output waveform]

---

**Update:**

After reading the detailed response from @SamGibson, I made the signal generator output as unipolar and tested the board.

The following are the snapshots of input and output:

1MHz Input signal from Signal Generator
[image: 1MHz Input signal from Signal Generator]

1MHz Output signal
[image: 1MHz Output signal]

4MHz Input signal from Signal Generator
[image: 4MHz Input signal from Signal Generator]

4MHz Output signal
[image: 4MHz Output signal]

Comment: What does the input waveform look like?

Comment: I have added snaps of Input waveforms

Comment: What is it driving? How much capacitance is there on the line?

Comment: @Colin At present, it is not driving any loads

Comment: There obviously is some capacitance. Are you using any cables, connectors, or oscilloscope probes?

Comment: Ya, I am using High Impedance probes to view the out form custom board, which is connected to an oscilloscope. The probe may have around 20pf of capacitance.

Comment: what is probe  bandwidth? what is probe GROUND lead size? 6"? 1 meter?

Comment: any non-zero-size piece of metal will have electric-fields, which requires change-of-charge to change the voltage.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I am using this one : https://www.banggood.in/DANIU-1-Set-P6100-DC-100MHz-Oscilloscope-Probe-100MHz-Scope-Clip-Probe-for-Tektronix-p-1157645.html?gmcCountry=IN&currency=INR&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgcs&utm_content=lijing&utm_campaign=ssc-ing-tools-13anv&ad_id=379604905148&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIh7f_1tyC5QIVWg4rCh35ggGZEAQYBSABEgKRifD_BwE&cur_warehouse=CN

Comment: are you using GROUND plane? is oscilloscope set on full bandwidth?

Comment: Yes, The custom board has split ground planes. " is the oscilloscope set on full bandwidth?" What does it mean?

Comment: I am using this oscilloscope https://www.scientificindia.com/uploads/product/pdfs/100-mhz-70-mhz--digital-storage-oscilloscope-509.pdf

Comment: leading edge looks like there needs to be buffering before and after the chip.

Comment: Please show a photograph of the board (while it's being measured).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am feeding 1.8Vpp from signal generator

Your oscilloscope traces show that **the input signal to the SN74LVC1T45 is invalid**, and therefore you should not expect normal behaviour at the IC's output. This is due to the incorrect setup of (or lack of ability to control) the signal generator which is providing that input signal to the IC, as its output is a **bipolar** signal (i.e. it swings both positive *and* negative with respect to 0 V).

**Summary:** Make the signal generator output a **unipolar** (positive only) 0 V to 1.8 V waveform, and try again.

---

**Details:**

Both of the oscilloscope input traces (at 1 MHz and at 4 MHz) show the problem, but the extra overlay of information on the 4 MHz input trace shows the details more clearly. Therefore I'll explain the problem using your original 4 MHz input scope trace, with some added markings:

[image: Oscilloscope trace from question showing 4 MHz input signal, with added annotations]

Meaning of numbers added to the above image:

1. This shows the Channel 1 *zero volt* (sometimes called ground) marker. (The Channel 1 *trigger* marker is nearly on top of the Channel 1 zero volt marker, since the trigger voltage was set at just 40.0 mV. That is why the black "1" in the yellow left-pointing triangle is not quite so obvious as on the output trace images.)

   Notice how the IC's input signal (i.e. the signal generator's output signal) is bipolar i.e. it swings positive and negative with respect to 0 V. This is common for signal generator outputs which have not be setup to produce a unipolar digital signal.
2. This icon shows that Channel 1 is DC-coupled, so the voltage measurements shown below are referenced to zero volts.
3. This block of data again confirms point 1 above. I'm not using `Vpp`, `Vmax` and `Vmin` since those values include the overshoot & undershoot. Instead, look at `Vamp`, `Vtop` and `Vbase`.

   - `Vamp` shows that, ignoring over/undershoot, the signal has an amplitude of 1.78 V. That fits with the stated 1.8 Vpp amplitude of the signal generator output. However...
   - `Vtop` shows that the maximum signal amplitude is (+) 920.0 mV
   - `Vbase` shows that the minimum signal amplitude is **minus** 860.0 mV

   That all confirms that the signal generator's output signal (i.e. the input signal to this IC) is bipolar, which is invalid for the input to this IC and therefore does not guarantee normal behaviour.

   The input signal *should* not drop below 0 V (standard logic level requirement, stated as "V<sub>I</sub> Input Voltage" on page 5 of the [SN74LVC1T45 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1t45.pdf), under Recommended Operating Conditions)). Even the absolute maximum rating for minimum input voltage is -0.5 V (although that can be exceeded if the clamp current rating is not exceeded). **But** there is no guarantee of *correct behaviour* once the input signal drops below 0 V.

   When the signal swings positive then, after the overshoot, the SN74LVC1T45 IC's input voltage sits at 920.0 mV (`Vtop`). However according to the [SN74LVC1T45 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1t45.pdf), when the power supply is 1.8V, the minimum voltage guaranteed to be recognised as a logic high (V<sub>IH</sub>) is V<sub>CCI</sub> x 0.65. However this means (1.8 V x 0.65 =) 1.17 V is the *minimum* valid logic high input voltage, so 920 mV (0.92 V) is not a valid input voltage, even when the bipolar input signal is positive instead of negative. This is another way in which the IC is being operated outside its specification shown in the datasheet.

**Summary:** Make the signal generator output a **unipolar** (positive only) 0 V to 1.8 V waveform, and try again.

Comment: I, followed your instructions and made the output from the signal generator as unipolar and tested. I have added snapshots of the same.

Comment: @MightyBeard007 - Sorry for my delayed reply, I missed your update. (a) FYI your update (like with any new information added later) should not be in an *answer*, but should be added to the bottom of the original question as an *edit*. This is one way in which Stack Exchange sites are different from typical internet forums. (b) Those new scope traces confirm my answer, don't they? With the correct waveform generator settings, they show the expected 5V output waveform shape (allowing for ringing due to scope ground leads etc), instead of the distorted waveforms shown at the start. Any questions?

Comment: I removed High-value pull-up resistors at outputs and added 150R in series as a damping resistor. Now the output waveform has improved a lot. no ringing, overshoot and undershoot effects.

Answer (score 3):

I see output rise and fall times of about 25ns, which I think is consistent with the datasheet (which is a little sparse on such data). I think what you are seeing is the same behavior of the device, but as you increase the frequency you also decrease the time/division on the scope, which makes the rise and fall time more apparent.

Comment: The datasheet specifies the worst-case t_PLH as 7.2 ns.

Comment: @CL. t_PLH is propagation delay, from 50% on the input to 50% on the output. It is not the fall time. You could infer that the fall time should be of the same order of magnitude and maybe it is...my guess of 25ns was very pessimistic.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The propagation delay cannot be smaller than the fall time.

Comment: @CL. Sure it can...theoretically. These timing parameters are not measured to the same voltage levels, and there is no law that says that the falling edge has a uniform slope. The output could fall to 50% very quickly, but take considerably more time to reach the lower threshold of "fall time". I'm just saying that we can not make blanket statements like this. We must have the data from the manufacturer.